# Не работает git pull и вылетает непонятная ошибка

Tags: git, github

В общем, вижу, что в ветке есть какие-то изменения, которые могу спулить себе, находясь в ветке, где нету незакомиченных изменений.

Вбиваю git pull и получаю:

```
From blablabla.net:wr/BlaBlaProject
 ! [rejected]          epic/blablaBranch -> origin/epic/blablaBranch  (non-fast-forward)
```

Эта ветка в которой я не разу не работал и не выкачивал себе локально.

Пробовал выкачать ее себе, а потом переключиться на свою ветку и снова сделать pull, но все равно ошибка.

Не понимаю природу ошибки, так как git не пишет в чем конкретно проблема

Comment: "Пробовал выкачать ее себе" - как именно?

Comment: ошибка выглядит так, как будто вы не pull, а push делаете...

Comment: ну как же не пишет? очень даже пишет: «non-fast-forward». коммит, на который указывает ветка в том хранилище, куда пытаетесь получить, отсутствует в истории коммитов там, откуда пытаетесь получить. образно выражаясь: не получается к имеющемуся коммиту прицепить цепочку новых коммитов.

Comment: и, да: `не выкачивал себе локально` — действительно, ветку «выкачать» ни физически ни эмпирически невозможно. ветка — это всего лишь указатль на коммит. несколько десятков байтов информации. а вот коммит (и его предков), на который указывал этот самый указатель, по умолчанию git, конечно же, «выкачал». когда делали clone либо pull (не уточнив ни в том ни в другом случае, какой именно указатель вас интересует).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего причиной ошибки является то, что в удалённом репозитории кто-то принудительно переписал историю (`push --force`).

В этом случае проще всего удалить локальную ссылку на удалённую ветку командой `git branch -r -d origin/epic/blablaBranch`, и заново выкачать её вместе с остальными через `git fetch`.

**UPD**

Другой возможной причиной является то, что у вас запрещён `merge` при `pull`. То есть запрещено выполнять `pull` для веток, в которые вы локально коммитите. Это запрет включается или параметром `--ff-only` в смой команде `git pull` или в конфиге в параметре `pull.ff` значением `only`. Проверить значение в конфиге можно командой

```
git config --get pull.ff
```

Если действительно стоит такой запрет, то вместо `pull` делайте последовательно `fetch` и `merge` с нужными параметрами.

Comment: Пробовал. Не помогло=(

Comment: Точнее, да, я могу забрать ветку со свсеми изменениями, но пуллить все равно не выходит...

Comment: @iluxa1810, дополнил ответ

Comment: git config --get pull.ff ничего не возвращает

Comment: Что ты имеешь ввиду про удаление локальной ссылки на удаленную ветку? Как это сделать?

Comment: @iluxa1810, когда вы делаете `git fetch`, то для удалённой ветки origin/epic/blablaBranch создаётся её локальная копия, которая хранится в файле .git/refs/remote/origin/epic/blablaBranch. Её нужно удалить командой `git branch -dr origin/epic/blablaBranch`

Comment: она только локально у меня удалится? На сервере ветка останется?

Comment: Заработало, спс

Comment: @iluxa1810, да, удалится только локально. В справке https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch специально сделан упор на сочетание флагов -r и -d.